# Valid location of localhost

Tags: java, css

**I am Java newbie.**
What is the location of localhost?

I am placing my css file at this location
C:\Test Workspace\MyApp\cssFiles

Test Workspace is the name of my eclipse workspace.

In the jsp (in MyApp) where i am using the css file, i have written:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/MyApp/cssFiles/BackgroundIMGE.css" media="screen">
```

But while running the application in chrome, error comes like this

GET http://localhost:8080/MyApp/cssFiles/BackgroundIMGE.css 
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/cssFiles/BackgroundIMGE.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Maybe i am doing mistake in giving the correct location.

Comment: There is not one fixed location on your harddisk that represents 'localhost'. It depends on what web server you are using and how it's configured.

Comment: You will need to post more info.. What application server/frameworks are you using? What operating system?

Comment: The file must be served by the web server. Hint: your local filesystem is not reachable from the browser (which is a good thing).

Comment: What is the location of your HTML file?

Comment: Can you please post the `HTML` sample, as well as ensure that the file is in the correct folder, with the correct name/spelling

Comment: The location of your css and other files normally is relative to your application, i.e. using your example in the final artifact (.war-file, exploded folder etc.) they would be located in `/cssFiles/` inside the `MyApp` artifact (e.g. MyApp.war) and would be referenced that way, i.e. `href="/cssFiles/BackgroundIMGE.css"`.

Comment: @Jesper i m using tomcat. Struts Windows 64 bit. Anything else??? :-D

Comment: Location of my jsp is C:\Test Workspace\MyApp\WebContent @Mistalis

Comment: @Bonatti i am not sure where i should put the cssFiles folder in MyApp and what location should be given in jsp.

Comment: This has nothing to do with CSS itself. Please, remove the CSS tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse, then you should keep your `cssFiles` folder just under `MyApp/WebContent` folder. After you build the project, the `cssFiles` folder should go directly under your web app root directory (MyApp).

Comment: and what should i provide the location here:<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/MyApp/cssFiles/BackgroundIMGE.css" media="screen">

Comment: http://localhost:8080/cssFiles/BackgroundIMGE.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). It is still not working

Comment: Please try with your original one `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/MyApp/cssFiles/BackgroundIMGE.css" media="screen"> `

Comment: http://localhost:8080/MyApp/cssFiles/BackgroundIMGE.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Please stop your tomcat and keep your folder `cssFiles` directly under `WebContent` and then clean the project. Now run the the web app.

Comment: Are you running your web app from Eclipse?

Comment: I wasn't refreshing my project!!! There the problem came. Otherwise what u recommended was right. Thanks